# Notice: Undefined variable: _Session

Tags: php

Looked through all the other PHP Session pages that I thought were relevant, and couldn't find what the problem on my page would be. Below is my code for the 3 pages:

Login.htm (This works)

```
      <body>
  <section class="container">
    <div class="login">
      <h1>Login to Web App</h1>
      <form method="post" action="checklogin.php">
        <p><input type="text" name="login" value="" placeholder="Username or Email"></p>
        <p><input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password"></p>
        <p class="remember_me">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="remember_me" id="remember_me">
            Remember me on this computer
          </label>
        </p>
        <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="commit" value="Login"></p>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div class="login-help">
      <p>Forgot your password? <a href="index.html">Click here to reset it</a>.</p>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="about">
    <p class="about-links">
      <a href="http://www.cssflow.com/snippets/login-form" target="_parent">View Article</a>
      <a href="http://www.cssflow.com/snippets/login-form.zip" target="_parent">Download</a>
    </p>
    <p class="about-author">
      &copy; 2012&ndash;2013 <a href="http://thibaut.me" target="_blank">Thibaut Courouble</a> -
      <a href="http://www.cssflow.com/mit-license" target="_blank">MIT License</a><br>
      Original PSD by <a href="http://www.premiumpixels.com/freebies/clean-simple-login-form-psd/" target="_blank">Orman Clark</a>
  </section>
</body>
```

checklogin.php (this works, session is successfully created, you can see my testing in code to make sure the session is actually set)

```
<?php
session_start();
$con=mysqli_connect("someServer","root","somePassword","someDatabase");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
//Get the two variables for login and password from the form on login.htm
$user = $_POST['login'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
//Write out your MySql Query
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM members where username = '$user' and password = '$password'");
//Get the row number your query sends out. This is to make sure the username / password combo actually exist
$num_row = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ( $num_row == 1 )
{
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
//Get the data from MySQL
  echo $row['username'] . " " . $row['password'];
  //Set whatever is in username to the variable $user1
  $user1 = $row['username'];
  echo "<br>";
  echo $user1;
  echo "<br>";
  //Start Sessions
  //set the session username5 to whatever was in the SQL table for user
  $_Session['username5'] = $user1;
  //Read off the session stored variable
  echo $_Session['username5'];

}
} else {
echo 'That shit didnt work';
}

// rest of page . . 
if ($_Session['username5']) {
header( 'Location: https://localhost/avesi/login_success.php' ) ;
}else{
echo "Login Failed!";
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Login_success.php (this is where I get the error - Notice: Undefined variable: _Session in C:\xampp\htdocs\avesi\login_success.php on line 10)

```
<?php
session_start();
echo time();
if (!empty($_SESSION['username5'])) {
echo "Not empty";
}else{
echo "Empty";
}

echo $_Session['username5'];
?>
```

On checklogin.php, it returns the username in the echo for $_Session['username5'], so I know a session is set.

On Login_success, I get the "empty" from the echo, and the error from the echo $_Session['username5']; like its not set at all anymore.

Both pages reference session_start() so I'm not sure what the problem is. I am pretty new to PHP so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: PHP variables are case sensitive. `$_SESSION['username5']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is case sensitive, a quick fix would to make all instance of session to CAPS.

like so $_SESSION['username5'];

Comment: This was it... I didnt even think about checking case sensitivity... too used to Windows I guess. Thanks!